# How to apply back-propagation algorithm to the local contrast normalization layer in convolution neural networks?

Tags: networking, convolution

I read the back-propagation algorithm and understood that to compute the gradients of network parameters, an error term should be back-propagated from the last output layer to the first hidden layer. But when I use the local contrast normalization layer in convolution neural networks, I found it is not clear how to back-propagate the error term.

The description of local contrast normalization layer can be found here:
 http://code.google.com/p/cuda-convnet/wiki/LayerParams#Data_layer

Comment: I encountered the same question in implementing deep learning, but solved. 
To do back-propagation, you only need to get the derivative of 'input to a unit(k) in layer(l + 1)' at 'output of a unit(j) in layer(l)'. 
In normal fully connected layer, the derivative is just a 'weight' between j and k.
But in LCR(local contrast normalization) layer, the derivative is calculated as a formula including normalization parameters.